# Returning None when scraping href using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, href

Hi I'm trying to scrape `151 Heavy Duty Rubber Gloves - Ex Large` from table with following inspect script. Can someone please help with the right Python script?

```
[<table border="0" class="ProductBox" id="Added0">
<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="2">
<div style="width:100%;float:left;display:inline;float:left;height:37px;"><div style="float:left;font-size:16px;font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;color:white;margin-top:4%;margin-left:6%;"> </div></div>
</td></tr><tr>
<td align="center" colspan="2" height="60px;" valign="top">
<div class="PromoPriceText"> <br/><br/></div><div class="StdPrice">£0.69</div><div class="UnitCost">(£0.69/Unit)</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="2" height="185">
<a href="/products/DetailsPortal.asp?product_code=104373&amp;Page=Products&amp;BreadPath=/products/gridlist.asp?DeptCode=14*prodgroup=211" style=" line-height: 20px; padding-left: 0px;">
<img alt="" class="effectfront" id="prod" src="/~uldir/104373t.jpg" style="height:165px !important;"/></a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ProdDetails" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;margin-bottom:5px;"><input name="product_code" type="hidden" value="104373"/>104373</td>
<td align="right" class="ProdDetails" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;margin-bottom:5px;">
                     
                </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ProdDetails" colspan="1" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;margin-bottom:5px;">
                    POR 0%

                </td>
<td align="right" class="ProdDetails" colspan="1" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;margin-bottom:5px;">
                    VAT 20%

                </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ProdDetails" colspan="2" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;margin-bottom:5px;height:50px;">
<a href="/products/DetailsPortal.asp?product_code=104373&amp;Page=Products&amp;BreadPath=/products/gridlist.asp?DeptCode=14*prodgroup=211" style=" line-height: 20px; padding-left: 0px;">
                    **151 Heavy Duty Rubber Gloves - Ex Large**</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ProdDetails" colspan="1" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;margin-bottom:5px;">
                    1s x 1 
                </td>
<td class="ProdDetails" colspan="1" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;margin-bottom:5px;float:right;width:98%;text-align:right;">
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="IconWishNS" id="IconWishNS104373" onclick="AddToWish('104373','A')" style="display:inline-block;">
<span class="tooltiptext tooltip-bottom" style="font-size:12px;">Add to Wish List</span></div>
</div>
<span class="OKStatus">In Stock </span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;margin-bottom:5px;">
<table style="margin-top : 10px;" width="100%">
<tr>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="minusone(document.getElementById('104373_qty')); return false;"></a><img align="middle" alt="Take 1 Off Qty" src="/images/minus.png"/>
</td>
<td>
<input class="iQtyBox" id="104373_qty" maxlength="4" name="104373_qty" oninput="this.value=(parseInt(this.value)||'')" tabindex="1" type="text" value="1"/>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="addone(document.getElementById('104373_qty')); return false;"></a><img align="middle" alt="Add 1 To Qty" src="/images/add.png"/>
</td>
<td align="right">
<a href="#" onclick="AddToBasket('104373',document.getElementById('104373_qty'),0);return false;"></a>
<button class="subBlackButtonDiv subButtonDiv" style="width:70px;margin:0px;" type="button" value="add">Add</button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I tied to use the following

```
        r = s.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        table = soup.find_all('table')
        
        for i in table:
            links = [link.get('href') for link in i.find_all('a')]
            print(links)
```

which unfortunately returns: `['/products/DetailsPortal.asp?product_code=104373&Page=Products&BreadPath=/products/gridlist.asp?DeptCode=14*prodgroup=211', '/products/DetailsPortal.asp?product_code=104373&Page=Products&BreadPath=/products/gridlist.asp?DeptCode=14*prodgroup=211', '#', '#', '#']`

Comment: If you're interested in the text of the link, have you tried something like `links = [link.text.strip() for link in i.find_all('a')]` ?

Comment: it gives me the following result:
['#', '#', '#']

Answer (score 0):

Can use the `td.ProductDetails a` selector (an `a` tag inside `td` with the class `ProductDetails`) to target the text you are interested in, then call `.strip()` a few times to remove extra characters:

```
DATA = """<table border="0" class="ProductBox" id="Added0">
<tr>
...
</table>"""
 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from typing import Optional

def extract_name(data: str) -> Optional[str]:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
    links = soup.select("td.ProdDetails a")
    if len(links) >= 1:
        return links[0].text.strip().strip("*").strip()
    else:
        return None

print(extract_name(DATA))

# like above

r = s.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
tables = soup.find_all('table')
text = extract_name(tables[0])
```

Output: `151 Heavy Duty Rubber Gloves - Ex Large`

Comment: Thanks @Sean, the above code returns None every time, am I doing anything wrong here?

        DATA = """<table border="0" class="ProductBox" id="Added0">
        <tr>
        ...
        </table>"""
        
        def extract_name(data: str) -> Optional[str]:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(DATA, 'html.parser')
                links = soup.select("td.ProdDetails a")
                if len(links) >= 1:
                    return links[0].text.strip().strip("*").strip()
                else:
                    return None
        print(extract_name(DATA))

Comment: Ah sorry, Instead of `DATA`, pass `r.text` to `extract_name`, or any other `table`/`html` string you want to extract the name from. e.g. `extract_name(r.text)` There was a slight error in the example I had above hat may have caused that issue, have fixed that

Comment: Not sure I follow, do you mind updating the above script that you posted?

Comment: I did, check the code below the `# like above` comment, matches what you posted in your question. You could pass the entire `r.text` to the function, or extract a table first with `find_all` and then pass the first item in the list like I did in the example

Comment: Thanks - I managed to extract it by using product_name = soup.find('td', {'class': 'ProdDetails', 'colspan': '2'}).text.strip()

I have another question now if you can help. I'm also trying to extract 1s x 1 in one of the tr, however, if you see it has class: ="ProdDetails" colspan="1" and that particular class and colspan is also used for values VAT 20% and POR 0%. Is there a way to only filter value 1s x 1?